# Eclipse and Background Compile like Resharper in Visual Studio

Tags: eclipse, resharper

In Visual Studio with Resharper I can set the project to background build as I type. A red icon on the status bar appears the instance I code something wrong. Green if all is good. It does this by compiling all the time.

Is there a way to enable this in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the default mode for Eclipse. Make sure the "Build Automatically" option is checked on the "Project" menu, and check the "Problems View" for any build errors and warnings.